# Create new variable where NA correspond to 0 and non-NA to 1

Tags: r, na

I am trying to create a new variable that has a value of `1` if a different variable has any, non-`NA` number, and a `0` if the other variable is `NA`.

So the variable has values like:

```
c(3, NA, 1, 2, NA)
```

...and the new variable should be:

```
c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0)
```

I tried to use `ifelse`, and it worked to turn the numbers into a 1 but all the `NA`s are still `NA`s.

```
mydata$variable_presence <- ifelse(mydata$old_variable > 0, 1, 0)
```

I also tried testing for `NA` but that just came up as an error.

```
mydata$variable_presense <- ifelse(mydata$old_variable = NA, 0, 1)
```

Any advice?

Comment: The answer by won782 is actually much better than using `ifelse`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple `is.na()` function will do.
Boolean (logical) in R can easily be coerced to binary (1 if true, 0 if false).

```
data = c(3, NA, 1, 2, NA)
as.numeric(!is.na(data))
```

will do the job.